# How to update JQuery for IE Edge

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013

I am fairly new on jQuery. I use VS2013 to build the app. I need to update a web app for IE Edge. The app has old version of the jQuery and I download the update version. My app didn’t work.

I update the meta tag:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```

I replaced the old version with update version which, I downloaed it at https://jquery.com/download/ , as below:

•   jquery-1.4.4.min.js -->jquery-2.1.4.min.js

•   jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js -->jquery-ui.min.js

There are some jquery. After searching the web,  I still have no idea to update it:

•   jquery.contextMenu.js

•   jquery.query-2.1.7.js

•   jquery.cookie.js

I got the error on contexMenu.js. I search the word “mozilla” on that page, but I didn’t find it.

[image]

When I include the jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js.  There is no error but some function doesn’t work such as popup calendar is appearance with unselectable  and the page is locked.

Would someone tell me how to solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: you probably won't find it, SOMEWHERE the code is doing `undefinedarray[var_that_contains_mozilla]` or simillar.